# Objective-C reentrant function

Tags: objective-c, deadlock, reentrancy

I'm quite a newbie in Objective C and I ran into this following problem:

```
-(void) funcA
{
   // array is NSMutableArray within class definition and initialised at alloc method
   [array setLength:0];
   ...    
   // make search and delegate itself for callback to funcB
}

-(void)  funcB:(NSData*) data 
{
    [array: appendData:data];
}

(void) funcC
{
      //Finished collecting data
      //Signal caller for funcA that all data is received.
}
```

The idea is the funcA is called to connect to a server that appends data multiple times by calling funcB and then finally funcC when all data is sent. This is OK.

The problem I have is that funcA can be called multiple times which leads to that the array will be set to length 0 while it is in the middle of processing the old request.

Now I have tried [NSLock lock] in funcA and [NSLock unlock] in funcC but then the lock call on second request makes a deadlock. I understand synchronize is another way of getting around this but i have only seen the block within a function.

I usually program in C and I would use pthread_mutex but I want to stick to obj C all they way. Assuming that they are different threads but it seems they aren't (because of deadlock).

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.
Indy

Comment: Since these methods are instance methods of whatever class they're in and, presumably, the array would be an instance variable (or property), can their caller just create a new object for each request?  It's not an answer to your actual question but might be a more OOP way of avoiding the situation in the first place.

Comment: Generally (there are exceptions) if you need to lock in one method and unlock in another you've got a poor design.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you're just looking for a reentrant lock. `pthread_mutex` is not recursive by default, but as an *option*. `@synchronized` is recursive. `NSLock` is not.

If that's your need, you can use `NSRecursiveLock`.

Comment: Justin, Thanks! That was it. That was all I needed. I completely missed in the docs.